# addTableModelListener do nothing when I recharge myScrollPane.getViewport()

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I load a JScrollPane (with a JTable) when I load the application.
I have a TableModelListener to save changes when table changed.

```
    table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent evt) {
          // UPDATE SQL into MDB
        }
    });
```

The UPDATE into MDB works fine.

So, I've a JTextField and a Jbutton too. When I write a date and I do click Jtable shows only the new records from MDB.

```
    myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            myScroll.getViewport().remove(table); // Remove old table
            // New SQL sentence
            table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
            myScroll.getViewport().add(table); // Load new table

        }
    });
```

Then, it works fine. Jtable show only matching record(s) from MDB.
But in this point, I explain my problem.

TableModelListener to save changes when table changed no longer works.
Only works with the initial JTable, but doesn't works with new JTable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there is no need to create and add a new JTable. just update the data in existing JTable.

Comment: So only two lines: table = new JTable(data, columnNames); and myScroll.getViewport().add(table);? That way TableModelListener doesn't work

Comment: Why are you creating a new Instance of the `JTable` on every Button click? Get the TableModel from your current Table and add a new Row.

Answer (score 2):

> *TableModelListener to save changes when table changed no longer works. Only works with the initial JTable, but doesn't works with new
>   JTable.*

Yes, because you create a new [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) in this line:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ...
    table = new JTable(data, columnNames); // <-- here
    ...
}
```

Consequently a new [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) is created and your listener isn't attached to this new one but the previous one.

IMHO you should reconsider re-create the `JTable` every time the button is pressed. Generally speaking tables (and their models) are created just once and then developers work adding/deleting/updating the table model.

Take a close read to table model sections, starting with [Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), of [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial.